# How to write a byte in a 32bit wide Block RAM

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx-ise

I have a BLOCK RAM (single port ram) generated with the following parameters:

```
Memory Type: Single Port RAM 
Write Enable: Use Byte Write Enable =  Disabled 
Write/Read Width = 32 
Write/Read depth = 131072
```

and it is working fine.
Now I want to write individual bytes for example byte 0,1,2 or 3 with respect to a 32 bit word. How can I achieve this using a byte-write access with block ram. I tried the following, but, it could not read out or write in any data (neither 32bit nor 8-bit).

```
Memory Type: Single Port RAM
Write Enable: Use Byte Write Enable = Yes,
Byte Size :8
Write/Read Width = 32
Write/Read depth = 131072
```

In the first case the write signal was:

```
we     <= "1" when (not(datarw_cpu = '0') and  datareq_mem = '1' ) else "0";
```

and in the second case the write enable is:

```
we <= "1111" when (not(datarw_cpu = '0') and datareq_mem = '1' ) else "0000";
```

Can any one please help.

## BLOCKRAM.BMM

```
ADDRESS_SPACE pr_mem1 RAMB32 [0x00000000:0x0000ffff]
BUS_BLOCK
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[15].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[14].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[13].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[12].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[11].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[10].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[9].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[8].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[7].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[6].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[5].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[4].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[3].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[2].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[1].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
    BROM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[0].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
END_ADDRESS_SPACE;

ADDRESS_SPACE pr_mem2 RAMB32 [0x00010000:0x0008ffff]
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[120].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[112].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[104].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[96].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[88].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[80].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[72].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[64].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[56].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[48].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[40].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[32].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[24].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[16].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[8].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[0].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[121].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[113].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[105].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[97].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[89].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[81].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[73].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[65].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[57].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[49].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[41].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[33].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[25].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[17].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[9].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[1].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[122].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[114].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[106].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[98].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[90].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[82].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[74].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[66].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[58].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[50].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[42].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[34].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[26].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[18].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[10].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[2].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[123].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[115].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[107].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[99].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[91].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[83].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[75].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[67].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[59].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[51].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[43].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[35].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[27].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[19].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[11].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[3].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[124].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[116].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[108].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[100].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[92].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[84].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[76].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[68].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[60].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[52].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[44].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[36].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[28].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[20].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[12].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[4].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[125].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[117].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[109].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[101].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[93].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[85].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[77].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[69].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[61].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[53].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[45].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[37].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[29].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[21].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[13].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[5].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[126].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[118].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[110].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[102].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[94].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[86].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[78].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[70].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[62].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[54].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[46].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[38].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[30].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[22].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[14].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[6].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
    BUS_BLOCK
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[127].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [31:30];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[119].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [29:28];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[111].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [27:26];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[103].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [25:24];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[95].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [23:22];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[87].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [21:20];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[79].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [19:18];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[71].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [17:16];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[63].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [15:14];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[55].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [13:12];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[47].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [11:10];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[39].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [9:8];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[31].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [7:6];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[23].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [5:4];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[15].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [3:2];
        BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[7].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP [1:0];
    END_BUS_BLOCK;
END_ADDRESS_SPACE;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see any mistake. Make sure you compile everything correctly w/o errors or warnings. Maybe post a screenshot of your simulation waveform.

Comment: It is working in ISIM, but gave errors during translation. Without the byte-write access i was using the attached blockram.bmm file. But, as we byte-write access how the blockram.bmm file can used? Should I used 9 bit as byte size? The error during the translation are: The BRAM instance 'BRAM_instance/U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/ramloop[120].ram.r/v5_noinit.ram/SP.SINGLE_PRIM36.SP' could not be found in the netlist. and so on

Comment: @Juergen, dear the above blockram.bmm is used to map the instruction rom to 0x0000-0xffff and the data ram to 0x10000-0x8ffff. I want to use same address space but with byte-write access in data ram.

Comment: What I would try: regenerate the BMM file through your tool chain. If this does not solve your issue, check the instance paths in the BMM file, maybe they need to be adapted to your specific design hierarchy.

Comment: Dear @Juergen, I removed the previous blockram.bmm for debuging. I implemented the design again without any .bmm file and then using PlanAhead I found that the BLOCK RAM is mapped to following:


U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/has_mux_a.A/Mmux_dout_mux_2_f7 (MUXF7)
U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/has_mux_a.A/Mmux_dout_mux_2_f7_0 (MUXF7)
U0/xst_blk_mem_generator/gnativebmg.native_blk_mem_gen/valid.cstr/has_mux_a.A/Mmux_dout_mux_2_f7_1 (MUXF7)

It is not using PRIM36.SP as before. How can I fix this problem to write bmm.

Comment: Another option is to write HDL code that synthesizes to single port block ram rather than using the Xilinx block ram generator.  You could code up 4 single port block rams with a write width of 8 bits and depth of 131072, then control the write enable to each of the 4 separately.